# how can I successfully compile a Dart app when I get a "late" modifier error (Unexpected text 'late')?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following line here (I am trying to add a flutter package which uses it):

```
class _PersonaWidgetState extends State<PersonaWidget> {
  late InquiryConfiguration _configuration;

 @override
   void initState() {
     super.initState();

   _configuration = TemplateIdConfiguration(
     templateId: "TEMPLATE_ID",
     environment: InquiryEnvironment.sandbox,
     fields: InquiryFields(
     name: InquiryName(first: "John", middle: "Apple", last: "Seed"),
      additionalFields: {"test-1": "test-2", "test-3": 2, "test-4": true},
     ),
```

Even though 'late' is an accepted modifier in dart, I get the following:

```
persona_widget.dart:26:3: Unexpected text 'late'.
```

I don't think there's a way around it since I need the functionality provided by "late" and wouldn't know what modifier to substitute for it.

This is the setting for the sdk in the `pubspec.yaml`:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
```

**Edit:**

```
• Flutter version 2.10.5 at /Users/timfong/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 5464c5bac7 (3 weeks ago), 2022-04-18 09:55:37 -0700
    • Engine revision 57d3bac3dd
    • Dart version 2.16.2
    • DevTools version 2.9.2
```

Comment: Can you check `flutter doctor -v` or just `flutter --version`

Comment: Yes, just updated @YeasinSheikh

Comment: Can you try with `flutter create .`

Comment: it seems to work now by removing 'late'

Answer (score 3):

With the introduction of NNBD (Non-Nullable By Default) in Dart 2.12, a new keyword was created: late. The primary reason this was created was to allow for non-null fields, that did not have to be immediately initialized.

**Solution #1:** Migrate the whole project to null safety. I think this is the best option as without null safety you'll be missing a lot of new features.
For Null Safety migration: https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide

**Solution #2:**
You can just remove the late keyword.

from:

```
late InquiryConfiguration _configuration;
```

To

```
InquiryConfiguration _configuration;
```

Comment: Solution #3:

Migrate to null safety and make the InquiryConfiguration nullable.

`InquiryConfiguration? _configuration;`

Answer (score 1):

`late` is for projects `converted` to `null safety` using min dart `sdk 2.12`. It tells the `compiler` that it's null now but will be initialized later on. You can either omit the `late` keyword in that case or change the min sdk in your `pubspec.yaml` to `2.12`.